# What is the return type hint of a generator function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, yield, type-hinting

I'm trying to write a `:rtype:` type hint for a generator function. What is the type it returns?

For example, say I have this functions which yields strings:

```
def read_text_file(fn):
    """
    Yields the lines of the text file one by one.
    :param fn: Path of text file to read.
    :type fn: str
    :rtype: ???????????????? <======================= what goes here?
    """
    with open(fn, 'rt') as text_file:
        for line in text_file:
            yield line
```

The return type isn't just a string, it's some kind of iterable of strings? So I can't just write `:rtype: str`. What's the right hint?

Comment: returns a generator with strings

Comment: Looks like you're not asking for a type hint but a docstring insertion for `:rtype:`

Comment: People mark as duplicate without even reading the question. Sigh...

Comment: @Wood Look again...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett The other question asks for the type annotation. This one asks for the docstring insertion for `:rtype:`. They are different things.

Comment: @Wood Look again at who "people" is... I can assure you, I read my own question. And the other one.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett It's typical in the IT community for people to solve their own problems and not share how they did it with other people. You being the author of the question should not give you the right to falsely mark it as duplicate.

Comment: Note that (currently) sphinx is able to automatically extract the return type (`rtype`) from the corresponding type hint ...

Answer (score 162, accepted):

[Generator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator)

`Generator[str, None, None]` or `Iterator[str]`

Comment: Is there a new answer now that Python 3.9 supports more complex type hints?

Comment: @NathanDai In Python 3.9 the syntax is basically the same, you just import the `Generator` class from `collections.abc`. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43659081/244297) for the details.

Comment: Furthermore, from Python 3.9 `typing.Generator` is deprecated in favour of [`collections.abc.Generator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Generator).

Answer (score 93):

As of Python 3.9, you can annotate a generator using the `Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]` generic type from [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Generator). For example:

```
from collections.abc import Generator

def echo_round() -> Generator[int, float, str]:
    sent = yield 0
    while sent >= 0:
        sent = yield round(sent)
    return 'Done'
```

In earlier versions of Python you can import the [`Generator`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.Generator) class from the `typing` module. Alternatively, `Iterable[YieldType]` or `Iterator[YieldType]` from `typing` can be used.

Comment: What's the difference between `Iterator` and `Iterable` when using for type hinting the yield action?

Comment: @DanielLavedoniodeLima I guess, `Iterable` is more generic, while `Iterator` indicates that the result can be iterated only once.

Comment: `Iterable` provides you an `__iter__` method which returns an `Iterator`. It's essentially a  factory for iterator objects. On the other hand `Iterator` iterates over (yields) consecutive elements. The iterator keeps the current position and returns elements.
In short, the `Iterable` gives you an `Iterator` which you use to retrieve elements of that `Iterable`

Answer (score 13):

Comparing `Iterator` with `Generator`...

The docs define `collections.abc.Generator` as an "ABC for generator classes that implement ... the `send()`, `throw()` and `close()` methods".

So I use `collections.abc.Iterator[ReturnType]` for a 'plain' generator, and reserve `collections.abc.Generator` for cases where I have implemented `send()`/`throw()`/`close()`.